# How can connect Grails with oracle db?

Tags: oracle, grails

How can connect Grails with Oracle DB?

Please any help me, I can connect grails connect with Oracle DB function method.

Comment: do you have the oracle's jar ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your project folder, navigate to grails-app\conf and then edit the file DataSource.groovy in your favorite editor. Make changed for "datasource" and "development" sections.

Comment: You will also need to edit `build.gradle` to add a dependency on whichever Oracle JDBC driver you want to use.

Comment: Edit DataSource.groovy for grails 2, or either application.yml or application.groovy for grails 3.  If you're using grails 2, you'll edit BuildConfig.groovy rather than build.gradle.